# TSQL Looping through rows which do not contain sequential ids

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to loop through each row in a table to perform some action. The primary key of the table is a GUID identifier so I can't really use that in my loop. This is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @RowCount INT
SET @RowCount = (SELECT COUNT(EmploymentIdentifier) FROM tblEmployment)

DECLARE @I INT
SET @I = 1

WHILE (@I <= @RowCount)
BEGIN
    --Just some variables I'll be using later
    DECLARE @PaymentTypeOld int, @PaymentTypeNew uniqueidentifier

    -- How do I select each unique row here? I'm stuck at:
    SELECT TOP 1 FROM tblEmployment WHERE EmploymentIdentifier == ???

    //Logic goes here..

    SET @I = @I + 1

END
```

I tried playing around with `ROW_NUMBER()` but kept getting syntax error with regards to using OVER incorrectly.

It doesn't matter in what order I process the rows, as long as all rows in the table are processed.

Comment: You want to use a cursor.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx

Comment: Agree with @jhilden on the surface.  Anytime I hear cursor when dealing with relational set data I first ask Is there a better way...  So depending on what your doing, a cursor will work, but it may not be the best solution to your problem. but it does address this symptom.

Comment: @xQbert and jhilden Thank you both. I'll be reading the value from one column then based on that value I'll be inserting a new value into another column for the very same row. 

I'll be doing that for all rows in that table. Is a cursor the way to go for this?

Comment: What is the action that you are attempting to do?

Comment: Yes, specifically then you want to use "WHERE CURRENT OF" within your cursor.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188713%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: I'll disagree with @jhilden here.  If you are doing an update statement `update some table set some value = some other value where some condition is true` I'd process this in a whole set not as a cursor. as a whole cursors are slower. both will work; but in this case I think set processing is better than record processing.

Comment: you could do that with a case statement and no cursor.

Comment: Ok, I'm getting confused now. Could someone kindly provide a minimal example, simply reading a column value of say integer type and multiplying it with two to store it in another column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only set myField = current value *2 when col1 has a value of 1 When col1 has a value of 2 then myfield would be multiplied by 3.  If col1 is anything else myField is left unchanged.

```
Update myTable set MyField = Case when Col1 = 1 then MyField*2  
                                  When Col1 = 2 then MyField*3
                                                else myfield end
```

You could also do multiple conditions...
now both Col1 must be `1` and col2 must be `N` before we multiply results by 2.

```
Update myTable set MyField = Case when Col1 = 1 and Col2 ='N' then MyField*2 
                                                              else MyField end
```

It could be a simple where clause too which reduces the overhead of records to process seems like the most efficient if we only need to update certain records to a specific value, but if all records must be updated and the update varies by record, then case statement is the way to go..

This simply multiples myField by 2 when col1 is 1.

```
Update mytable set myField = myField*2 where col1=1
```

Comment: I'm curious why the case examples are given here? Seems the update with a where clause is the simplest example and least likely to confuse.

Comment: It has to do with if different activities need to occur based on the value in col1.  Say when col1 is 1 we want to take myfield*2, when col2 is 2 we want to multiply myfield by 3.  you can't do that in a single update using a where clause.  you would have to use multiple or more complicated SQL than a case.

Comment: The use of case examples is EXACTLY what I need. I didn't know how to express this in SQL. Thanks!